# Cannot find contract attachment for flow

Tags: kotlin, corda

After upgrading corda to version 4, I am getting net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.contract.ServiceContractnull.

This flow works locally but throws the error message when deployed to Azure.

I have

- Checked that my all my cordapps are located in /opt/corda/cordapps -folder
- My contract ID is "com.template.contract.ServiceContract"
- I'm not running any test

I have tried to change SERVICE_CONTRACT_ID="com.template.contract" but that didn't work either

CreateServiceFlow

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class CreateServiceFlow(val serviceState: ServiceState) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

        serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<ServiceState>().states.forEach{
            if (it.state.data.serviceName == serviceState.serviceName) {
                throw Exception("There can be only one ${serviceState.serviceName} service per service " +
                    "provider")
            }
        }

        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first()

        val serviceCommand = Command(
            ServiceContract.Commands.IssueService(),
            serviceState.participants.map { it.owningKey }
        )

        val builder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
            .addOutputState(serviceState, ServiceContract.SERVICE_CONTRACT_ID,
                constraint = AlwaysAcceptAttachmentConstraint)
            .addCommand(serviceCommand)

        builder.verify(serviceHub)

        val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(builder)

        val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(serviceState.accountOperator)

        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(otherPartySession)))


        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, setOf(otherPartySession)))
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(CreateServiceFlow::class)
class IssueServiceResponder(val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartySession) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                "there should be no inputs" using(stx.inputs.isEmpty())
                "there should be one output" using(stx.tx.outputStates.size == 1)
                "The state should serviceState" using(stx.tx.outputStates.single() is ServiceState)
            }
        }
        val txId = subFlow(signTransactionFlow).id
        return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession, expectedTxId = txId))
    }
}
```

ServiceContract

```
package com.template.contract

@LegalProseReference(uri = "<prose_contract_uri>")
class ServiceContract : Contract {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val SERVICE_CONTRACT_ID = "com.template.contract.ServiceContract"
    }

    val legalContractReference: SecureHash
        get() = SecureHash.randomSHA256()

    interface Commands : CommandData {
        class IssueService : TypeOnlyCommandData(), ServiceContract.Commands
        class AddServiceData : TypeOnlyCommandData(), ServiceContract.Commands
        class AddPartner: TypeOnlyCommandData(), ServiceContract.Commands
        class RemovePartner: TypeOnlyCommandData(), ServiceContract.Commands
        class ExitService : TypeOnlyCommandData(), ServiceContract.Commands
    }

    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {....
}
```

When running createService flow POST request to remote node-webserver it throws

```
net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.contract.ServiceContractnull. See https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.selectAttachmentThatSatisfiesConstraints(TransactionBuilder.kt:445) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]...
```

UPDATE: This is the response I get when I run the same flow locally

```
{
  "wire": {
    "id": "3EDD9204FF70AF2B36D78219690946004C7D5625D347F04EE55980A8600141BF",
    "notary": "O=NetworkMapAndNotary, L=Helsinki, C=FI",
    "inputs": [],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "data": {...},
        "contract": "com.template.contract.ServiceContract",
        "notary": "O=NetworkMapAndNotary, L=Helsinki, C=FI",
        "encumbrance": null,
        "constraint": {
          "@class": "net.corda.core.contracts.AlwaysAcceptAttachmentConstraint"
        }
      }
    ],
    "commands": [
      {
        "value": {
          "@class": "com.template.contract.ServiceContract$Commands$IssueService"
        },
        "signers": [
          "GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyVMCDbvndZWywoFqaPKbGgxeqVUEVBYgpNTqFTqc7mVqe",
          "GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyWB97whuGdtsB8c7EByHbsTxkdsNq695JX8PKSwDPq3d9"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "timeWindow": null,
    "attachments": [
      "17B22D590137C675AC1B61B7052CCEF739AA36223865BBFF707E6CB2F933FBF0"
    ],
    "references": [],
    "privacySalt": "0AFC86A1BBF6D897CCC5AA56F0FC0474DE4CD618FF040BAA96293BAA1BCDBCAF",
    "networkParametersHash": "31AF29974115E6BE4418C4080F58DFD77F301E45DC35A05DB855B0D1B25966B2"
  },
  "signatures": [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Azure deployment are you running with `devMode=false` in your `node.conf`?

It could be that your code is signed by the corda dev key which can only be used in development mode (as the key is not secure), which would mean that the deployed node is not loading your CorDapp.

In order to test whether this is the issue in your azure deployment, you can try adding this line to your `node.conf`:

```
cordappSignerKeyFingerprintBlacklist=[]
```

By default the Corda dev keys are in that list, emptying in the list would cause your application to be loaded. See https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html#corda-configuration-file-signer-blacklist for more information.

You can read more about signing jars here:

https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html?highlight=signed#signing-the-cordapp-jar

Comment: Yes, there was indeed `devMode=false` in node.conf. This solved it, thank you.